# Запуск Swift на Windows

Tags: windows, ios, swift, apple, swiftui

Возможна ли работа и отладка Swift в Windows 7 Home Edition?

Answer (score 0):

Нет, невозможна. Для отладки нужен Xcode, который для Виндовс не выпускается.

Comment: Для отладки не нужен Xcode. На Linux его нет, а отладка работает.

Comment: @DmitrySerov можно гайд? ищу сам.

Comment: Гайд для чего? Отладка на Linux, как и на macOS, идёт через lldb. Гуглить по запросу "debug swift on Linux lldb".

Comment: А кросскомпиляция возможна?

Comment: Кросскомпиляция невозможна.

Answer (score -1):

На самом деле Swift работает на Windows, но только начиная с Windows 10.
Отладка в Windows-версии пока не поддерживается до конца и нет полной поддержки менеджера пакетов.
Обычный компилятор работает и все стандартные библиотеки языка есть.